# How can I version bump all my dependencies?

Tags: javascript, dependency-management, yarnpkg

Having `yarn outdated` is quite informative but I'd like to avoid running over package by package doing `yarn upgrade`.

From yarn's documentation, just `yarn upgrade` without arguments is said to upgrade all dependencies but there's no change in my project's `package.json` and `yarn outdated` shows the same packages versions than before.

Is there some command or argument that just bumps all my dependencies?

If not, is the practice discouraged in some way?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can update your packages to the latest version specified in the package.json using `yarn upgrade` without any args.

This is taken from the [docs](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/upgrade#toc-yarn-upgrade):

> `yarn upgrade`
>
> This command updates all dependencies to their latest version based on
>   the version range specified in the package.json file. The yarn.lock
>   file will be recreated as well.

This will only update packages that are allowed to be upgraded in the package.json e.g. using `^` (e.g. `^0.13.0` would update to version `0.14.0` if it exists). This will not update your package.json file, but it will update the yarn.lock.

If you want to update dependencies in to the latest version you can use the package `npm-check-updates` which will update your package.json:

```
$ yarn global add npm-check-updates
$ npm-check-updates -u
$ yarn upgrade
```

Comment: Right. Maybe it does. But it's not reflected in my `package.json` and `yarn outdated` shows no difference before and after a full run of `yarn upgrade`. What am I missing?

Comment: I realised that `yarn upgrade` only updates packages to the latest version in the package.json if you are using `^` or `~`. If your package is specified as a fixed version this will not change. I have edited my answer to add an option to update your package.json.

Comment: Have you tried `yarn upgrade --latest` command? According to the documentation, as I understood, it updates the package.json as well.

Answer (score 137):

Upgrade all packages to latest version

```
yarn upgrade --latest
```

Comment: That only upgrades `yarn.lock` for me, how can I make it so that it als updates `package.json`?

Answer (score 46):

just run `yarn upgrade-interactive --latest` and select packages you want to update using space button and press the enter to update.

Comment: NOTE: You will need to import the `interactive-tools` plugin for `yarn` before using `upgrade-interactive`, by running this command: `yarn plugin import interactive-tools`.

Answer (score 19):

Answer for users of Yarn v2 and above.

Import the `interactive-tools` plugin:

```sh
$ yarn plugin import interactive-tools
```

And run it like this:

```sh
$ yarn upgrade-interactive
```

Note that this will also modify the semvers in your `package.json`.

Comment: Correct answer for 2022, including Yarn v3

Answer (score 8):

If your dependencies are using a range version (`"^x.x.x"`, `"~x.x.x"`, etc), your `package.json` won't be updated if the latest version also match that range, only your `yarn.lock`.

If you want your `package.json` to be updated:

1. Change all your dependencies to a fixed version (`"x.x.x"`)
2. Run `yarn` to update the `yarn.lock`
3. Run `yarn upgrade-interactive` and select all dependencies you want to upgrade

Now both your `yarn.lock` and `package.json` will reflect the exact latest versions.

Answer (score 2):

You could also copy your dependecies to a typescript or javascript playground and use `Object.entries(obj).reduce((xs, x) =>` ${xs} ${x[0] }`, "yarn add")` to generate the command containing all of the packages inside your `package.json`.

### Example

```
let obj = {
    "@types/react": "^16.3.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.6",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "del": "2.2.2",
    "es-cookie": "^1.2.0",
    "es6-promise": "4.1.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.0.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-jshint": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-merge-media-queries": "0.2.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-rev-all": "^0.9.7",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.1",
    "jshint": "^2.9.4",
    "node-promise": "^0.5.12",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "require-dir": "^0.3.2",
    "run-sequence": "1.2.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.3",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2",
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-log": "^1.2.0"
  }

  let res = Object.entries(obj).reduce((xs, x) => `${xs} ${x[0] }`, "yarn add")

  console.log(res)
```

Output:

> yarn add @types/react @types/react-dom awesome-typescript-loader babel-polyfill del es-cookie es6-promise gulp gulp-autoprefixer gulp-clean-css gulp-concat gulp-if gulp-jshint gulp-merge-media-queries gulp-rename gulp-rev-all gulp-sass gulp-uglify jshint node-promise react react-dom require-dir run-sequence source-map-loader typescript webpack webpack-cli webpack-log

I use this playground to quickly generate the command. It is also usefull to quickly generate code from json objects.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=35&ssc=19&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBA9gRgVhAvBA3gKApiAiAAmATwAcQBnAegCcQBDAYzGwC4cA9ARgDYA6AZm-YAObABoMWPIRIVq9MAFoAJlAC2zNl24AGbp1HjM2GgHcyqkPKlk6lAJZEFwKDUUhK67KwCsA7fqw4MDQwIMDyRFDABABmtsDAHqw8AEw8Wv4Srgks2MnceckZhmTydFBQANa2IIns+X5iAdhknOGUqrakNTkALL7sRTgA5gCuwESJfTqFjRKj4-I0I2BQRNSxAB5uifx1A7OG80SloDQAdqWkpDva+YPYR6VQZ3Q0jDmseTz7BsNjx7Zook8tN7o84KQABa2M7vNgg7g9MH-eQqNxDCxoxS2GjyACOIzc1WuOWmAmRC2oZxoaNq9RmvweKOoADdFvFEjoAJzcADsFOOpBoVxudXSBz+CxGQ2AgIIwNuPyaEOhsIVPKREuwZygrjaHS6nO4PnYDKasgYtR4fSVEgtCmUag+mht92oBNs1CUnqN-DNdpGFy6BJAL26ODqBXupCgI0odExNGOThc2w+ZN49yspBs9jhnjyPP9hlMMCI9AqkwEIPupfLdAqJ1sNx0wi1dYr8icQzpNfEAF80OJQJBqKQkBAAPLwEAMbihsB2MgAClgcAAlNxqIoRgnl8uNqQRBANuukAA+CAAAwAJChD-2IHeNgBtLQAXQg-avx+wBBolBnBALiKNg65DpgZRnDGoDcN2y5juuQA

Answer (score 0):

jq two liner:

```
 cat package.json | jq   '.dependencies | keys[]' -r | xargs yarn upgrade --latest
 cat package.json | jq   '.devDependencies | keys[]' -r | xargs yarn upgrade --latest
```