# Is this correct, ng update --all only shows the upgrade options available?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-upgrade

If I run the command

```
ng update

I see a listing of items such as
@angular/cdk  6.4.7 > 8.2.0   ng update @angular/cdk
...
...
```

> There might be additional packages that are outdated.
>
> Or run ng update --all to try and update all at the same time.

It does not appear that the command by itself ng update makes any changes.

So, does the execution of the `ng update --all` make changes?

I just want to see ALL packages are detected to need updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: The `ng update` command allows for packages separated by spaces to be specified with additional arguments:

```
ng update [packages] [options]
```

Check out the [`ng update` command docs](https://angular.io/cli/update) for more info.

---

This is because by default, the `ng update` command when specified without any arguments/packages will try to update all of the packages if possible.

Here's the portion of the code of the update command which checks if no packages were specified:

```js
if (options.all || packages.length === 0) {
      // Either update all packages or show status
      return this.runSchematic({
        collectionName: '@schematics/update',
        schematicName: 'update',
        dryRun: !!options.dryRun,
        showNothingDone: false,
        additionalOptions: {
          force: options.force || false,
          next: options.next || false,
          verbose: options.verbose || false,
          packageManager,
          packages: options.all ? Object.keys(rootDependencies) : [],
        },
      });
    }
```

From the code above, this also means that either specifying the `--all` option or not specifying any options at all will try to update all of the packages.

---

Note: You can view the entire [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/v8.3.4/packages/angular/cli/commands/update-impl.ts) of the `update` command to see how the command works.

Comment: "the ng update command when specified without any arguments/packages will try to update all of the packages if possible."
This is not what the current documentation says, "Without additional arguments, ng update lists the updates that are available to you and provides recommended steps to update your application to the most current version."
Has this command changed? If so, that's quite a big change from updating everything to updating nothing.

Answer (score 8):

If you willing to upgrade to major version of angular you should refer to this site: https://update.angular.io/

**Angular 11+:** use the update command of your package manager:
NPM: `npm update` [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32363790/7132461)
YARN: `yarn upgrade` [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41213295/7132461)

**Prior to angular 11**:

In early 2020, `ng update --all` simply updates all packages.

Around late 2020, the `--all` flag [is deprecated](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/824add1778d70a76d302acaf85168800c687cc35#diff-3f7305eaa0a0edb2fec614e0fb51916b485c6f1ff012341109165c23a8bca404):

> `--all` functionality has been removed from `ng update` as updating multiple packages at once is not recommended. To update the depencencies in your workspace 'package.json' use the update command of your package manager

Comment: Output for me:
        '--all' functionality has been removed as updating multiple packages at once is not recommended.
        To update packages which don’t provide 'ng update' capabilities in your workspace 'package.json' use 'npm update' instead.
        Run the package manager update command after updating packages which provide 'ng update' capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

On new versions of Angular this is no longer included, but you can replicate it mostly with:

```bash
ng update --force $(jq -r '.dependencies * .devDependencies | keys | map(select(startswith("@angular"))) | @tsv' package.json)
```

(then run: [`ncu`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) `-ux '/typescript|rxjs/'`)

My issue to bring the functionality back: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/23261